# Reassigning the caps lock key on Windows or OS X

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard

How can I remap the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key in Windows or OS X? Is there, for example, some way to map caps lock to a key combination like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> on OS X?

[image: CAPS LOCK]

Comment: YES, PLEASE TELL ME - HOW CAN I DISABLE THIS DARNED THING!?  ;-)

Comment: CapsLock might be the most useless key nowadays. '[Lenovo Vice-President David] Hill called “Caps Lock” a frustrating hangover from typewriter days, a key that can introduce garble, emulate shouting or foil password entries without the user noticing.', http://www.insidetech.com/news/articles/5143-lenovo-tries-to-improve-keyboard-layout-in-latest-notebook

Comment: Unbelievable that four years have gone by, and Windows STILL does not have a built-in way to permanently disable Caps Lock and Num Lock.

Comment: This question really is two questions in one. It would have been better to have one question for Windows, and one question for macOS.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) and this script:

```
;Deactive CapsLock key 
$CapsLock:: 
return
```

Autohotkey is THE most powerful way to do this sort of thing on a WIndows PC.  Also see [this page](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic38088.html) for more details on re-mapping CAPS,

Comment: Very nice, thank you! As soon as I have time I'll look into it.

Comment: Was coming to suggest the same thing. I've remapped CapsLock to Escape to aid in Vim editing :D

Comment: I've remapped Caps to LCtrl. It was a lot more natural for my hand go to the left that turn -60degres and extend the little finger to grab the LCtrl key. After months of this change the pain that i was felling to doing that repetitive movement was gone completely

Comment: This does not work with my japoanese keyboard. Instead, the CapsLock key gets replaced by the [半角／全角 key](http://mintclub.kobe-np.co.jp/img/manual20100816c.jpg).

Comment: @wil: on Japanese keyboard, pressing shift+Capslock will do normal Capslock function

Answer (score 11):

I've used [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys/releases) (for windows) to remap <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Works great for [vim](http://www.vim.org). VI-style editing really shines if you can keep your fingers near the home row at all times.

Comment: This is the best tool I have come across in over 6 years of disabling the caps-lock key, mapping my IBM Model M's right ALT key to the Windows key, etc. It simply records to the registry the necessary changes, but has a nice interface to facilitate that effort. And it isn't installed as an _app_, it is a simple utility.

Comment: Too bad Windows-7 is not supported.

Comment: @WilliamKF: I am using SharpKeys on Windows 7. It works fine.

Comment: @WilliamKF: I'm also using SharpKeys on Win7. Chek that you execute it with administrative permissions.

Comment: Even better is mapping CapsLock to Ctrl. Ctrl+[ is the same as escape and now you have an easier to reach Ctrl for other key combinations.

Answer (score 9):

Here's how to swap the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key with left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

**Windows**

1. Click Start > Run
2. Type "regedit"
3. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`
4. While Keyboard Layout has focus, go to Edit > New > Binary Value
5. Enter "Scancode Map" as the name
6. Enter the following as the Data:

   ```
   0000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
   0008: 03 00 00 00 3A 00 1D 00
   0010: 1D 00 3A 00 00 00 00 00
   ```
7. Exit the Registry Editor
8. Log out and log back into Windows

**Linux**

1. Create a file in your home directory called .xmodmap if it doesn't already exist
2. Paste the following lines into the file:

   ```
   remove Lock = Caps_Lock
   remove Control = Control_L
   keysym Control_L = Caps_Lock
   keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L
   add Lock = Caps_Lock
   add Control = Control_L
   ```
3. Add the following line into ~/.bash_profile

   ```
   xmodmap ~/.xmodmap
   ```

[Source](http://steve.yegge.googlepages.com/effective-emacs)

Comment: It should be noted that most graphical environments on Linux offer a way to set the caps lock key behavior in whatever keyboard configuration tool it offers. It can also be modified in the standard keymap for the console.

Comment: Excellent. This was what I was looking for and I didn't find the solution with MSKLC. Thanks a bunch (and +1 of course).

Comment: hey, could you please answer me the esc key code? I want to swap Caps with Esc key.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/2006/07/sharpkeys_211.html) to disable the functionality of any key. For a detailed guide, you can check out [Map Any Key to Any Key on Windows XP / Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/).

Aditionally, Lifehacker has a really good guide called [NumLocker Disables the Caps Lock Key](http://lifehacker.com/5274189/numlocker-disables-the-caps-lock-key) on how to remap or disable it entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the SharpKeys link! Sadly, there seems no way to map a key to a combination of keys in the program (I read the FAQ).

Comment: @splattne for map a combination use Autohotkey. It is extremely simple to do it, for example: CapsLock:: SendInput !{Tab},  it will send Alt Tab when you press the Caps

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 7):

on Mac: You can reassign the caps lock key under "System Prefs" -> "Keyboard & Mouse" -> "Special Keys".

i assigned it to CTRL

Comment: On Snow Leopard, it's "System Prefs" -> "Keyboard" -> "Modifier Keys".

Comment: This is so damn simple, why do we need an app for this on Windows?

Comment: @WTP Better yet, for proper remapping (rather than AutoHotkey-esque macros) you need admin rights as well as of Windows 7. Begging IT in a corporate environment for that doesn't seem to be going over well for me.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Billy Mays Caps Lock](http://johnhaller.com/jh/useful_stuff/billy_mays_caps_lock/). Now whenever I accidentally hit the Caps Lock key instead of getting frustrated I hear a quick Billy Mays pitch, which always puts a smile on my face.

Answer (score 2):

SysInternals' [Ctrl2Cap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897578.aspx) will work on older Win machines, too.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac I can recommend using [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/document.html.en#usage).
Or [PcKeyboardHack](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/pckeyboardhack.html.en) which has a slightly different focus. I use both in combination without any problems.

The problem is, there is no out of the box solution built in to Mac OSX so you could assign <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd> to <kbd>ESC</kbd> (which is essential for Vi/Vim). The second problem with other tools is that they don't disable the green LED on the Caps-Lock Key.

`PcKeyboardHack` is related to the ESC-mapping, but every mapping is possible.
`KeyRemap4MacBook` directly allows to map to a different function key. For sure every mapping you like is possible So for example on Mac I have mapped the right <kbd>⌘</kbd>-Key to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  (what comes in handy when you are accustomed to eclipse-like autocompletion on Windows)

Comment: I just started using KeyRemap4MacBook this morning, and I love it. I have `caps lock` set to both `esc` and `ctrl`. It's `esc` when it's the only key being pressed, and it switches to `ctrl` if I press any other keys.

Comment: @Dean glad to hear about it!

Comment: FYI: KeyRemap4MacBook has been rebranded to Karabiner and even supports Yosemite (OS X 10.10)!  https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en

Answer (score 1):

Swapping it with a different modifier key (I like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) is supported by Mac OS:

```
keyboard control panel -> modifier keys
```

Answer (score 1):

As Marchal said, on OS X you can use [PCKeyboardHack](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/pckeyboardhack.html.en) to change caps lock to another key like F19:

[image]

You can map the key like F19 to a more complex key combination by adding a setting like this to private.xml in [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F19, KeyCode::CONTROL_L, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L |
ModifierFlag::OPTION_L | ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
```

If the caps lock light on your keyboard does not get disabled, try enabling the "Pass-Through caps lock LED status" setting in KeyRemap4MacBook.

This maps F19 to control when held and to escape when pressed:

```
<autogen>__KeyOverlaidModifier__ KeyCode::F19, KeyCode::CONTROL_L, KeyCode::ESCAPE</autogen>
```

You can also map F19 to an extra modifier key that can be used to for example activate applications:

```
<vkopenurldef>
  <name>KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_SAFARI</name>
  <url>file:///Applications/Safari.app</url>
</vkopenurldef>
<item>
  <name>test</name>
  <identifier>test</identifier>
  <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F19, KeyCode::VK_MODIFIER_EXTRA1</autogen>
  <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::S, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1,
  KeyCode::VK_OPEN_URL_SAFARI</autogen>
</item>
```

See http://lri.me/keyremap4macbook.html for more information about using KeyRemap4MacBook.