# How can I disable or reassign the 'Windows' key?

Tags: windows, keyboard

Between <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>, modern keyboards have an abominable key: the 'Windows' key :P

[image: Windows key shot]

By default, when this key is pressed alone it opens the Start menu. Many applications and a great number of games work in fullscreen mode, and if you press this key accidentally, most of times because you wanted to press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys, the application usually freezes for a while and  minimizes itself. If you are lucky, your videogame will pause, but sometimes it continues even when it is minimized.

#### Is it possible to disable the 'Windows' key?

It would be possible to show the Start menu with another combination of keys? I would like to keep combinations that use the Windows key working, like <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, which leaves current session.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See my answer for [Reassigning the caps lock key on Windows or OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/1193/how-to-disable-and-reassign-the-caps-lock-key/1250#1250):

> You can use [SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/2006/07/sharpkeys_211.html) to disable the functionality of any key. For a detailed guide, you can check out [Map Any Key to Any Key on Windows XP / Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. For an example, see http://superuser.com/a/85230/36744

Answer (score 4):

You can download SharpKeys! It saved my life, especially when I want to press ESC and accidentally press F1.

SharpKeys is free. You can download it from [here](http://www.randyrants.com)

- When installed, click on Add button,
- on *Map this key (from key)* section click on *Type key* button. Type F1.
- on the *To this key (to key)* section, select *Turn Key off* item.

Confirm with OK, reboot your Windows (because registry got changed).
You're done!

Answer (score 4):

Autohotkey?

That can do a lot more, too.

```
LWin::Return
```

disables it, but

```
#F::Run firefox.exe
```

would tell Win&F to run firefox. You could even set the winkey to only be disabled ingame, or require a double-press to fire, or have to hold it down before it triggers, and more!

Answer (score 3):

You can add a certain value to the Registry to disable it.  [Here is a good tutorial, and some .reg files you can download.](http://johnhaller.com/jh/useful_stuff/disable_windows_key/)

However, this will disable the key entirely, as in no WinKey shortcuts.  However, what I do is that I disable only the left Windows key, and use the right one to enter shortcuts.  It's a sacrifice, but it means that I don't minimize anything fullscreen by accident.

Answer (score 2):

Take a screwdriver, pry it off!  If that's a bit extreme, you can edit the registry to disable it.

Now, since you want to maintain some functionality (Win+L), but not others (Win) try using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to intercept the functions you don't want and do nothing.

Its a bit involved, but I think it will work the best.

On an odd note, apparently its the game developer's [fault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219746(VS.85).aspx)!

Answer (score 2):

Pick yourself up a quality gaming keyboard ([this one's great](http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/keyboards/keyboard/devices/4956&cl=us,en), but you can find much cheaper ones).  They usually have a switch that disables the windows key and the context menu key.

Answer (score 2):

I have a laptop purchased in Canada that has many keys that irritate me (necessary for Francophones, etc.) and I use KeyTweak (got my copy from Softonics), which I learned about from How-to-Geek, and changed the assignment of keys at will to suit myself.  Fun, free, and possibly a terrible practical joke issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a support article titled: Microsoft Support Article KB216893 [How to disable the keyboard Windows key](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=216893).

The article offers **Microsoft Fix It** downloads to enable/disable the Windows logo keys.

Alternatively, here's the manual procedure:

> #### To disable the Windows key, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click **Start**, click **Run**, type **regedt32**, and then click **OK**.
> 2. On the **Windows** menu, click **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE on Local Machine**.
> 3. Double-click the **System\CurrentControlSet\Control** folder, and then click the **Keyboard Layout** folder.
> 4. On the **Edit** menu, click **Add Value**, type in **Scancode Map**, click **REG_BINARY** as the **Data Type**, and then click **OK**.
> 5. Type **00000000000000000300000000005BE000005CE000000000** in the **Data** field, and then click **OK**.
> 6. Close Registry Editor and restart the computer.
>
> #### To enable the Windows key, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click **Start**, click **Run**, type **regedt32**, and then click **OK**.
> 2. On the **Windows** menu, click **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE on Local Machine**.
> 3. Double-click the **System\CurrentControlSet\Control** folder, and then click the **Keyboard Layout** folder.
> 4. Right-click the **Scancode Map** registry entry, and then click **Delete**. Click **Yes**.
> 5. Close Registry Editor and restart the computer.

Comment: If I apply this solution, will shortcut combinations (like Windows+L) still work?

Comment: @Auron: The regular shortcuts like Win+E, Win+D, Win+R will no longer function. However, Win+L is special because it is captured on a much lower level than the others. I was unable to confirm this right now, but it's possible that Win+L will still function after applying this change.

Answer (score 1):

best way is to pull the key out of the keyboard. you will never need it so why to stay and complicate with software and registry editors, just pull the key out nothing bad will happen you can pull it back anytime but you wont for sure. is useless. bye

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to temporarily disable the Windows keys while playing, I suggest that you give this little app I wrote:

> https://bblanchon.github.io/disable-windows-keys/

It's fairly simple: open the app to disable the Windows keys, close it to restore them.

[image]

It's an [open-source project hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/bblanchon/disable-windows-keys).
It's a native application, and therefore, has a minimal footprint.