# How to remap Windows key to a special modifier

Tags: windows, keyboard

I have 2 operating systems on my machine: Ubuntu Linux and Windows. On both systems Emacs is installed.

In Ubuntu "Windows" key sends "Super" modifier when pressed, and in Emacs I have attached several shortcuts to it like this:

```
(kbd "s-z")
```

On Windows this key is rigidly tied to operating system, and I though, it would it be possible to remap it to a separate modifier and add new settings to Emacs specific to Windows?

I have already remapped "Caps Lock" to Enter by adding `Scancode Map` parameter to registry node `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 1c 00 3a 00 00 00 00
```

Is it possible to add another parameter to remap Windows key to some special modifier using the same technique?

I read this answer: https://superuser.com/a/521137/145009. But I can't add a second value with the same name into the registry and what codes should I put?

Comment: Consider using a third-party program like AutoHotKey instead of hacking around in the registry.

Comment: See the accepted answer here and you'll know how to map multiple keys via Scancode Map https://superuser.com/questions/1539085/is-there-a-way-of-mapping-a-key-combination-of-a-computer-type-a-character