# AutoHotkey: problem assigning CAPS LOCK to ALT-TAB

Tags: windows, keyboard, autohotkey, hotkeys

Yesterday I asked [how I could disable or reassign the infamous CAPS LOCK key](https://superuser.com/questions/1193/how-to-disable-and-reassign-the-caps-lock-key/). The accepted answer pointed me to **[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)**, a powerful free, open-source utility for Windows for automating key strokes and mouse clicks.

The tool includes a script language and even a compiler (!) and it seems to work very well. For example, I managed to map the middle mouse button to the ALT-TAB key combination using this script in Windows Vista:

```
MButton::AltTabAndMenu
return
```

Now, I wanted to do the same reassigning the CAPS LOCK key to ALT-TAB:

```
CapsLock::AltTabAndMenu
return
```

But this doesn't have the desired effect. Instead of showing the "ALT TAB" running applications menu, it shows the Vista Start menu, as if I had hit the WIN key.

Any suggestions?

Comment: These both work for me in Vista.

Comment: You may consider mapping this authotkey script to capslock. It's more efficient than alt-tab if you have lots of windows: http://lifehacker.com/5278802/iswitchw-finds-windows-as-you-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me

```
CapsLock::AltTabMenu

return
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CapsLock UP::AltTabAndMenu
return
```

Comment: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work on my machine. Same behavior (opens Windows Start menu)