# Logitech Media Elite Func button

Tags: logitech-keyboard

I have the aforementioned keyboard, and occasionally the "Func" key will get unpressed. It gets especially annoying when I try to rename a file, and start winword by accident, or try to refresh a page, and nothing happens (It's the undo - no effect inside a browser usually).
I know I can rebind those keys to just do nothing, but I just wanted to know why does the func mode changes by itself? Can it be something with power management/screen saver?

Answer (score 2):

I have a Logitech keyboard almost identical to this and had the same problem.  Here's what [Logitech says](http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/logitech_en_amr.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=60):

> When you are using a corded iTouch
>   keyboard, the F-Lock function will
>   always be on when you boot your
>   computer. There is no way to change
>   how this feature works; however, you
>   can work around this feature using the
>   Transparent Pass-Through key
>   assignment. By programming a function
>   key to Transparent Pass-Through, the
>   Enhanced function is bypassed and the
>   function keys will perform their
>   normal purpose even though the F-lock
>   key is still on.
>
> ...
>
> If you are using a cordless keyboard,
>   the F-Lock feature will be in whatever
>   state it was prior to shutting down
>   Windows.  This means if the F-Lock
>   feature was on when you shut down
>   Windows, it will be on when you reboot
>   and if it was off when you shut down,
>   it will be off when you reboot.

Luckily, mine is cordless.

Comment: ok.. this sounds like a better solution. I will look into this "Transparent Pass-Through" feature (I have corded).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer for [How to disable and reassign the caps lock key?](https://superuser.com/questions/1193/how-to-disable-and-reassign-the-caps-lock-key/1250#1250):

> [Map Any Key to Any Key on Windows XP / Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/) is an awesome guide on how to remap the caps lock (or any other) button.

It is always giving it a shot to see if you can remap the 'func' key on your keyboard to another 'harmless' button (such as print screen, perhaps).

Comment: Got the software at home. Will check tonight if it recognizes the fun key. Thanks.