# Any gotcha's using Apple keyboards with Windows or Linux?

Tags: windows, keyboard

I used one of the aluminum Apple keyboards in a computer lab today and really liked it, and really want one, I just want to know if there are any issues that would arise when not using them with OSX.

A couple big questions:

1. Does the "delete" key (the one where a standard backspace key is) function as backspace, and the other delete key function as a normal delete key in windows?
2. Does the Apple key work as a Windows key in Windows? I know it will work as a super key in most linux distros.

I'm leaning towards the wired version, if that matters.

I'd really like to avoid spending hours (or more) configuring the thing. If I buy it, and plug it in, what issues might I encounter?

Answer (score 2):

> Does the "delete" key (the one where a standard backspace key is) function as backspace, and the other delete key function as a normal delete key in windows?

1. Yes

> Does the Apple key work as a Windows key in Windows? I know it will work as a super key in most linux distros.

2. Yes

The only thing to take into account is the sequence on a Mac keyboard used in Windows is from bottom left to right it goes Control, Alt, Windows ("Command" on Macs), whereas on a Windows keyboard it goes Control, Windows, Alt.

Comment: Yeah, that's the only thing. Otherwise it works great. I used to use it before I threw my pc into the dumpster.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as the Apple Keyboards are used with Windows all the time with Boot Camp, there is nothing wrong (and different) with using them on an actual PC. In fact, many will recommend it.

The only real gotcha is that the ctrl, alt and windows buttons are a bit jumbled up and the function keys may be enabled by default (apposed to pressing <kbd>fn</kbd> to enable them), and you might have to press <kbd>fn</kbd> every time you want to press <kbd>F3</kbd>.

You can remap the ctrl, alt and Windows key using [SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/2006/07/sharpkeys_211.html), which I [am](https://superuser.com/questions/1193/how-to-disable-and-reassign-the-caps-lock-key/1250#1250) [often](https://superuser.com/questions/9783/logitech-media-elite-func-button/9788#9788) [recommending](https://superuser.com/questions/1384/how-to-disable-reassign-the-windows-key/1399#1399):

> [Map Any Key to Any Key on Windows XP / Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/) is an awesome guide on how to remap the caps lock (or any other) button.
>
> Aditionally, Lifehacker has a [really good guide](http://lifehacker.com/5274189/numlocker-disables-the-caps-lock-key) on how to remap or disable it entirely.

Comment: When used in BootCamp, I know Apple provides a driver, which non-Mac users would not legally have access to.

Comment: The boot camp drivers are actually not that necessary. The keyboard (and mostly everything else) functions fine without them.

Comment: @Shadow The drivers are signed by Microsoft, so they are licensed under the Windows licensing terms.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the lack of "Print Screen" button to be incredibly annoying myself.  You'll be missing that and "Scroll Lock" and "Pause Break" (I don't use the latter 2 much).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you still have them, they're just labeled something else... forget which.

Comment: I've had some issues with Print Screen, but it is easily fixed. [More about that here](http://superuser.com/questions/722159/print-screen-on-windows-7-with-apple-keyboard).