# Disable the caps-lock key under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard, key-binding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable and reassign the caps lock key?](https://superuser.com/questions/1193/how-to-disable-and-reassign-the-caps-lock-key)

Is it possible to totally disable the <kbd>caps lock</kbd> key under Windows 7? Or reassign it to be another <kbd>shift</kbd> key?

I have done this on Mac OS X to avoid the annoyances of hitting the wrong key, and would like to be able to do it on Win7 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a how-to tutorial to either disable or remap the Caps Lock key in Windows 7.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/

Comment: regedit? I always feel slimy when I have to use that .. but I'll give it a shot :)

Comment: They have a zip file where you can download all the registry edits. It's at the bottom of the page. Each registry edit is named to correlate to what it does. That'll be better than doing it yourself. :)