# Remap Caps Lock in Windows (escape *and* control)

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, hotkeys

There's plenty of utilities that remap keys, but I can't seem to find a very specific feature: I want to have caps lock act as the control modifier key when held down, but as escape when pressed on its own.

A similar question was posed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/381296/mapping-caps-lock-to-escape-and-control-on-windows-7), and one of the answers provided an AutoHotkey script, however it is susceptible to the timing of key presses and only handles a hard-coded list of all possible control+letter combinations. I would prefer it if it would function without quirks, blocking caps lock pressed events, storing any other keys pressed while the caps lock key has not yet been released, and *then* deciding whether to send escape or control.

Is there a simple utility or a more generic AutoHotkey script that does this?

Comment: FWIW, whilst I also don't *like* the answer I posted, I haven't ever experienced any issues with it in practice, so if the answer below isn't working for you (as you state in comments), it's worth trying out, at least.

Comment: The answer you posted to the other question also seems to not work with key chords. Specifically, it seems to work only with *right* shift. For example, I'm pressing CapsLock+Shift+Tab and trying to get Ctrl+Shift+Tab. Pressing CapsLock+LShift+Tab doesn't seem to generate anything at all, but CapsLock+RShift+Tab works fine.

Comment: Not sure what's going wrong for you, but CapsLock+LShift+Tab works for me. (e.g. it successfully switches tabs in reverse order in Chrome.) I'm currently running on Windows 8.1 but I'm pretty sure it worked in Windows 7 and Windows 8, too.

Answer (score 17):

This script registers a single press on <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> as a press that lasts less than 400ms, modify that value as needed.

```
*CapsLock::
    Send {Blind}{Ctrl Down}
    cDown := A_TickCount
Return

*CapsLock up::
    If ((A_TickCount-cDown)<400)  ; Modify press time as needed (milliseconds)
        Send {Blind}{Ctrl Up}{Esc}
    Else
        Send {Blind}{Ctrl Up}
Return
```

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't work properly with multiple keystrokes, e.g. Ctrl+Shift+Tab or Ctrl+Alt+Del, although it works fine for 2-key combos like Ctrl-A or Ctrl-Tab.

Comment: I was missing an * before the first CapsLock hotkey.  The Ctrl+Shift combinations will work now.  Ctrl+Alt+Del however is a special shortcut that cannot be sent from AutoHotkey.

Comment: The asterisk doesn't seem to have made any difference for me.

Comment: works completely fine with ctrl+shift combinations for me. Thanks.