# Remapping a keyboard key in windows 8.1

Tags: keyboard, windows-registry, windows-8.1, keyboard-layout, key-binding

How can I remap keyboard keys in windows 8.1? I'm looking for a simple utility which will modify registry and would not require running at startup. I tried sharpkeys but, it does not seem to work in windows 8.1. Any other suggestions? Or a simple how-to tutorial for windows 8.1?

Edit: Keytweak isn't working either. Actually I want to map an unused key to function key (fn) and neither sharpkeys nor keytweak detect the keystroke for that key.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I've posted about such a thing [in this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/688889/permanently-disable-num-lock-in-windows/688895#688895).

To understand what is going on, [refer to this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/).

Here is the [full list of scan codes from Mirosoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa299374%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) so you can alter any key.

[image]
[image]

Here is the basic breakdown. You are editing a registry key. This particular one is set to map Numlock (45,00) to null (00,00) so that it's key does nothing. For some odd reason, re-mapping 1 key means you need to specify a 2 (02,00,00,00) in positions 17-24. Likewise if you map 2 keys, you'll need to specify 3 (03,00,00,00).

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,45,00,00,00,00,00
```

Comment: Problem is I want to remap menu key to this key: http://imgur.com/yriKWW9  and neither tools can find keybinding for same nor can I figure out from code.

Comment: on second look, FN is not really a key. See the first few paragraphs of The Fn key section here.  http://www.daonlyfreez.net/tutorials/3p/Veil/fnkey.htm

Comment: The 'odd' reason is not so odd: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/10/12/10074411.aspx

Comment: There are limits with rebinding a key when it comes to modifier keys.  Ran into this issue.  Also fn can be rebound in some cases like on Thinkpads but can't be used as a modifier unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Try *mapkeyboard* http://www.inchwest.com/mapkeyboard.htm
I am not sure, if it is able to detect the Fn key.

Answer (score 1):

Sharpkeys worked just fine for me, see my [windows 8.1 - mapping 1 key on keyboard to another](https://superuser.com/questions/867389/windows-8-1-mapping-1-key-on-keyboard-to-another).

I was trying to assign shift to a particular key on my keyboard.  MS Keyboard Layout Creator did not allow me to specify 'shift' as the replacement mapping (or I couldn't figure it out).  Sharpkeys did just fine, on Windows 8.1 on an ASUS gaming laptop.

I wonder if what happens is that *some* manufacturer's keyboard drivers don't play well with Sharpkeys under 8.1, rather than a blanket Sharpkeys does not work.

Comment: I thought SharpKeys is supposed to Create a `ScancodeMap` entry in the registry, I didn't see that get created...

Answer (score 1):

I recently found a VERY powerful yet FREE, simple and flexible tool that can be used for key remapping and much more. You can also compile your customizations (scripts) and provide them to others without the need to install the tool. It's called AutoHotkey (or AHK) and it seems to have a good user community. See the following 2 sites:
http://www.autohotkey.com/
http://ahkscript.org/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I have found for custom keyboard layouts on Win 8.1 is to use the Microsoft keyboard layout Creator 1.4 on another computer  with an earlier operating system. Windows xp worked for me.

After 5 hours of fiddling I came to the conclusion that Win 8.1 is incapable of building the appropriate files using the aforementioned software. It will allow you to load and modify keyboards but not save them.

On the older computer Run the software and load an existing keyboard. Modify it to suit your needs. Under the projects tab, click the build function and save the files to a usb stick.

Download and install Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4 on your Windows 8.1 computer and then run setup from the saved files on your usb stick.

It will load your customised keyboard straight to your keyboard toolbar at the bottom right of your screen. If you are using an earlier operating system than XP or Vitq you may have to download and install version 1.3