# Swap Caps Lock and Esc keys in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I am a Linux user who uses VIM as his primary text editor. Consequently I am used to remapping the Caps Lock key to function as Esc and vice versa.

I searched around for how to do this on Windows 8.1 and the only useful answers I found were around remapping Caps Lock and Left Ctrl.

[Map Caps-Lock to Control in Windows 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/764782/map-caps-lock-to-control-in-windows-8-1)

Answer (score 0):

Try [SharpKeys](https://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/). A tutorial is available [here](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-remap-keyboard-in-windows-78-1-using-sharpkeys/).