# Shift+Ctrl+Tab not working in chrome with mapped Caps Lock key in Windows using SharpKeys

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, autohotkey, keymap

As suggested by [this](https://superuser.com/questions/764782/map-caps-lock-to-control-in-windows-8-1) post, I used SharpKeys to map my Caps Lock key to Ctrl. A weird problem is that while other functions using this Caps Lock key as Ctrl works fine(like Caps Lock+Tab works fine in chrome for switching to next tab, Ctrl+W to close tab works fine), only Shift+Ctrl+Tab combination won' t work to go to previous tab. Using the real Ctrl keys+Shift+Tab works normally. Any idea on solving this problem?

I just upgraded to windows 10, this issue still occurs.

EDIT:

I just tried the following simple autohotkey script :`Capslock::Ctrl`. It works exactly same with the SharpKey approach. Shift+Ctrl+Tab still not working.

I tried with an USB external logitech wireless keyboard, it works fine. So I guess the problem is with my Bluetooth Keyboard, it is the bluetooth keyboard shipped with ASUS T300 Chi Pro.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reasoning for Caps Lock being required to begin with? There might be a better solution if we understand more.

Answer (score 0):

I tried testing this and can't reduplicate the problem you're having, maybe because my Windows version <8.1.

You may be able to try separate hotkey definitions, for example, explicitly defining Shift+Capslock to be Shift+Control.

```
Capslock::Ctrl
+Capslock::+Ctrl
```