# Changing Caps Lock's behavior for current user on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

I've tried to add the Scancode Map key to HKEY_CURRENT_USER with value

00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00
02 00 00 00
1D 00 3A 00
00 00 00 00

I've also tried adding an extra dword of 00s to the end as suggested for windows 8.1 in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/916887/65868).

I've restarted after each change.

Sadly, I cannot use the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE version of the key as my wife needs caps lock.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind installing [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) to achieve this, use this script:

```
+Capslock::Capslock
Capslock::Ctrl
```

Save it as a `AHK` file and execute it. Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> will revert to default CapsLock functionality.