# ESC key on laptop keyboard not working - use a macro instead

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard, macros, function-keys

I spilled beer on my laptop and now the <kbd>esc</kbd> key on my laptop’s keyboard does not work. I have Windows 8 installed on the laptop.

Is it possible to define a macro to simulate the <kbd>esc</kbd> key? I am wondering if the function keys can be used for this? For instance, I am wondering if Windows allows me to configure <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f11</kbd> to—in effect—cause an equivalent of an <kbd>esc</kbd> key press.

I cannot repair my laptop’s keyboard. I am hoping for a software solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I hope that was a good beer. Your computer seemed to enjoy it! But seriously, you are looking to remap the <kbd>esc</kbd> key and a tool like [SharpKeys](https://sharpkeys.codeplex.com) seems to be up to the task:

> SharpKeys is a utility that manages a Registry key that allows Windows
>   to remap one key to any other key. Included in the application is a
>   list of common keyboard keys and a Type Key feature to automatically
>   recognize most keyboard keys. It was originally developed in C# using
>   .NET v2 but has been updated to support .NET 4.0 Client Profile

Also, [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/694468/167207) seems to explain how you can do this yourself without the need for another software tool. With [more details here](https://superuser.com/questions/688889/permanently-disable-num-lock-in-windows/688895#688895).