# Would using a non-standard keyboard layout cause problems on different computers?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am going to start to touch type and I want to start on the "right" layout. However, a major concern of mine is that I might have to use other computers from time to time. To elaborate:

There are many many layouts alternative to qwerty to choose from. And AFAIK, only Dworak has made it as a standard (yet) and hence, choosable out of the box on many systems.

However there are many other layouts that are claimed to be better than Dworak. For that reason, I am tempted to pick one of them to learn to touch type on. However, these layouts are not made into a standard yet and hence, they cannot be found on many systems out-of-the-box.

Now the question is the following: If I make a configuration file for the (non-standard) keyboard layout that I will choose to use, would that be applicable to *any* system that I might encounter? For example: If I make configuration files for Linux, Windows and OS X for the keyboard layout that I will use, would that be applicable to *any* computer that I will be using or would there still be problems?

Comment: just look for a keyboard that guarantees that the codes which are sent to the system are the same like qwerty, so when you type a Q on both keyboards the corresponding digital signal should be the same. this has nothing to do with layout, just programming the keyboard chip (it 100% has one if it's an usb keyboard). So look for a standard compliant keyboard and you'll be golden.

Comment: @Gizmo So, if I use a programmable keyboard, then I won't have any troubles not matter which system I go to? (assuming that system has a programmable keyboard as well)

Comment: All usb keyboards are "programmable", I havent seen one (yet) in which you can program it, but my point is that if the creator of the keyboard decides to send the same signals for Q (and all other keystrokes) as a "normal" qwerty keyboard then there would be zero problems - a.k.a. standard compliant.

Comment: @Gizmo But does it be as simple as just putting some configuration file to somewhere or would it be more complicated?

Comment: I don't think there are such keyboards available, there may be services that offer keyboard customization for a service fee. You could also just take a standard keyboard, switch all keys the way you want them, and use a software solution, on windows you can use SharpKeys, on other systems you would need to research the possibilities. This is a non-portable way of handling this.

Comment: @Gizmo No, I am talking about putting a config file in the computer that I will be using.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/694465/remapping-a-keyboard-key-in-windows-8-1 (also, SharpKeys)