# Swap () and [] keys on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

I want to swap the keys for () and [] in order to have unshifted access to the more commonly used symbols. On Windows 7, I used a program called `parenswi` to do this, but it doesn't work on Windows 10, nor does an updated version seem to be available.

What's the best way to swap these keys on Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the free key-remapping product
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Here is a script for converting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd> to `[`.
It can easily be modified and extended, as I'm not sure that I have not
understood the question in reverse.

```
(::
if GetKeyState("Shift")
  Send, [
else
  Send, (
return
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Some AutoHotkey references:

- [If (Expression)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm)
- [GetKeyState](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GetKeyState.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can swap them by entering the relevant scancodes into the registry as described in this existing [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/694465/remapping-a-keyboard-key-in-windows-8-1) or use [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys/releases) to do it for you.

SharpKeys works by presenting you with a GUI where you pick the "to" and "from" keys and it then updates the required registry values automatically for you.  It  works fine on Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks! SharpKeys seems to be good at what it does, but it works by keys not symbols, so not applicable to this case of shifted vs unshifted symbols (it considers shift to be a key in its own right).

Comment: In that case perhaps [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm)  would be better with a mapping like `+[::Send {Raw}[`,  `[::Send {Raw}(` etc