# How to automatically enable numlock on Windows 10 logon

Tags: boot, login, numlock

Upon cold boot up or even a restart, the num lock is always disabled in Windows 10. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: try this: http://winaero.com/blog/enable-numlock-logon-screen-windows-10/

Answer (score 8):

I found a solution which worked beautifully on Windows 10:

1. I first tried to find a <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> option in the BIOS, but found none. ([ASUS G53SW](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/G53SW/))
2. I then tried to reboot from the login screen with <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> on to see if the system would remember it, but it didn't work.
3. I then tried changing values in the registry:

   ```
   HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard --> "InitialKeyboardIndicators"
   ```

   - Changed from default value `"214783648" to "214783650", which didn't work.
   - Changed to "80000002", which didn't work.
   - Changed to "2"`, which didn't work.

   I reverted it to "214783650", then for some strange reason I thought that maybe Windows tries to activate it, but has trouble communicating with the keyboard controller.
4. I went on my manufacturer's support site, downloaded the Intel chipset driver update utility, and the problem was solved.

Comment: So issue is with chipset? If I have AMD and same issue, then should I try it or stick with disabled `fast boot` option (because it also solves the problem)?

Comment: "80000002" worked for me. As well as '.DEFAULT' there were a number of other "S Users" e.g. `S-1-2-3` that I applied it to as well. Hopefully this helps somebody.

Answer (score 3):

There is a partial solution that involves setting **InitialKeyboardIndicators** to **2** in  `[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard]`. However this only works after complete reboot, not after **sleep**, **lock**, **hibernate**, or **fast startup**. In that case <kbd>Numlock ⇩</kbd> always turns off regardless of it's previous state.

Most laptops today use a fast startup, which basically hibernate your PC instead of shutting it down. You can disable this feature in your power settings. Then the numlock should be on after startup.

Disabling fast startup:

[image]

Please note that disabling fast startup may significantly increase your boot times on a standard HDD.

It will still turn numlock off when PC goes to **sleep** or **lock** sate or when you hibernate it manually tough. I'm sure you can find this issue in your localized **Windows feedback** app, support it so MS may fix it one day.

Comment: For me changing the value to "2" worked on Windows 10, with "Fast boot" enabled

Comment: This is part of the solution. I would have added my own, but my association bonus doesn't count. So I took it from [How to Enable Num Lock Automatically When Your Computer Boots](https://www.howtogeek.com/244606/how-to-enable-num-lock-automatically-when-your-computer-boots/) on How-To Geek. It states also to change the `InitialKeyboardIndicators` in several other directories.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no fix. Microsoft decide to let you log in by PIN, but the old registry hacks no longer work, so Num Lock is always disabled on boot.

Comment: PIN....??......you mean microsoft account?

Comment: @Moab PIN, as in... Since Windows 8 you can set a PIN to log in with

Answer (score -2):

1.Go to the following Registry key: HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard
2.Set the value "InitialKeyboardIndicators" to 2147483650. 
3. Restart (This will turn on NumLock on the logon screen starting from the next boot).

Comment: Have you tested this to make sure it works?  The value of the key is odd, in addition, the other answer says this doesn't work.  This also seems to be word for word from winaero.com