# Is it possible to have Num Lock ALWAYS ON, without the ability of the Num Lock key to turn off?

Tags: numlock

So this question is **not** about having num lock on by default.

Is it possible to have num lock turned on, and remove the ability of the num lock button on the keyboard to affect that state?

#### EDIT (because):

In my keyboard the <kbd>Home</kbd> button is really close to the <kbd>numlock</kbd>. At work I often use <kbd>Home</kbd> and the numpad, but sometimes I accidentally hit the <kbd>numlock</kbd> too. As a result my numpad gets turned off which is really sucks when I have to type a lot of numbers and after a while I realise I typed nothing because numlock turned off numpad.

Comment: remove the numlock key and epoxy the switch in the on position, pop the key back on.

Comment: W-why would you need that? just curious

Comment: @RegisteredUser see my edit

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/688895 + http://superuser.com/a/688891

Comment: Wish I can upvote you 100 times. Same here. Especially after I switch back and realized that `Insert` mode is on by hitting 0 and there is no indicator for that. I just don't get it. Who is using `Ins` in the 21st center?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use CapShift and it's free:

https://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Skrommel/index.html#CAPshift

"CAPshift extends the Caps Lock key by slowing it down...

- Hold down for 0.5 sec to enable/disable.
- Hold down for 1 sec to show the menu.
- Rightclick the tray icon to show the menu.
- Also slows down F1, Insert, NumLock and ScrollLock."

The Advantage is: You don't lose the ability to change NumLock if you really need to.

Comment: Sounds good but the installer does not run on Windows 8.1 :[

Answer (score 6):

Physically remove the NumLock key.  When your finger goes to press it, it won't be there.

Comment: The foolproof solution.

Comment: It is actually not foolproof. Some software (HyperV for example) can toggle numlock off again, and when you have removed the key from the keyboard (or used SharpKeys) you have to fool around and reboot to get it back on.

Answer (score 6):

If you use Autohotkey, you can add the following line to your script:

```
SetNumLockState, AlwaysOn
```

Be sure to put this line before your hotkeys. I put it at the very beginning of my script so I make sure it always works fine, if you put it in the middle or at the end of your script, it may not work.

Comment: If yer a AutoHotKey n00b like me, right-click in Startup, choose New | AutoHotKey Script, add that to it, and add #NoTrayIcon if you don't want an icon in yer system tray.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to automatically put it back on (within a few milliseconds) when it gets turned off, via an application.

This guy created an autohotkey script for it which he calls "Numlock Enforcer"
http://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?topic=9018.0

Not to most elegant solution, but it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but it solved that problem for me:

Activate the sound for the Lock keys in Windows (in Windows 10: Control Panel\Ease of Access\Ease of Access Center\Make the keyboard easier to use\Turn on Toggle keys)

That way, when you hit it, it beeps, and you realize it right away. It actually trained me to not hit it anymore at all, because the signal is right when it happens.

Comment: Nice idea, working with built-in functionality!

Answer (score 0):

The BIOS might have a setting to disable the NumLock key, but we need to know
your computer-model and BIOS-version to discuss this more in depth.
Typically, one boots into the BIOS and looks for an item named
"NumLock State", "Bootup NumLock State" or similar, press Enter
and use the arrow keys to select "Off" or "Disabled", then press Enter.

For Windows hackers, the registry contains in `HKCU\Control Panel\Keyboard`
an item named [InitialKeyboardIndicators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978657.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which has the undocumented value
of `1` to disable the NumLock. Its effectiveness may vary according to
the version of Windows.

The brutal solution is to pop off the Numlock key cap and use a pen to change
its setting when required. The setting will normally stick, since
Windows XP and later remember its state across boots
(unless the BIOS or other setting interferes).

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Change the registry to set initial state of NumLock to on at startup:

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard\InitialKeyboardIndicators
  Set to Value to 2
```

**Step 2**

Add an AutoHotkey script to monitor the key and ensure it cannot be turned off. [Install AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/download/), and create a new script named MyBestNumlockHack.ahk. Put this script in your C:\Users\{User Name}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup directory.

```
Numlock::
  if (!GetKeyState("NumLock", "T"))
    SetNumLockState, On
  return
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a timer and call it NumlOn.
Set the interval on 100.

```
Public Const VK_NUMLOCK = &H90
Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" Alias "GetKeyState" _
(ByVal ByValnVirtKey As Integer) As Short
Dim NLKey as boolean

Private Sub me_keyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.NumLock And Not NLKey Then
        If Not GetKeyState(VK_NUMLOCK) Then
            e.Handled = True
            NumlOn.Start()
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End sub

Private Sub NumlOn_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _ 
Handles NumlOn.Tick
    NLKey = True
    If Not GetKeyState(VK_NUMLOCK) Then numlockON()
    Application.DoEvents()
    NumlOn.Stop()
    NLKey = False
 End Sub
```

Comment: Where’s the beef? I suppose you want the use to put this code into a file. What then?  How do you use it?  How does it work? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot a sub...
This is fully working

```
Public Const VK_NUMLOCK = &H90
Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" Alias "GetKeyState" _
(ByVal ByValnVirtKey As Integer) As Short

Private Sub numlockON()
    keybd_event(VK_NUMLOCK, 0, 0, 0) ' Press NUMLOCK key down
    keybd_event(VK_NUMLOCK, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub me_keyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.NumLock And Not NLKey Then
        If Not GetKeyState(VK_NUMLOCK) Then
            e.Handled = True
            NumlOn.Start()
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End sub

Private Sub NumlOn_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NumlOn.Tick
    NLKey = True
    If Not GetKeyState(VK_NUMLOCK) Then numlockON()
    Application.DoEvents()
    NumlOn.Stop()
    NLKey = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Rather than posting multiple answers, please just correct the previous answer and delete this one, or delete that one if it needs the changes in this one.  Also, what Scott said on your other answer.