# Pressing "Enter" on Numeric Pad Turns Off NumLock (?)

Tags: windows-10, usb, keyboard, desktop, numlock

This started happening with a brand new Windows 10 machine. No matter what brand of USB based keyboard I use I keep having the same problem.

---

Here are the system specs: I will add any further information as necessary.

**Dell OptiPlex 3040**

**Windows 10 Pro x86-64**

**Dell USB keyboard model KB216**

---

Things I have already attempted:

- [This suggestion from SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1072172/num-lock-refuses-to-stay-on/1082238#1082238)
- [This other post on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1074391/windows-10-numlock-automatically-turns-off-after-5-seconds-of-no-activity)
- Swapping to a different USB port
- Updating BIOS
- Updating device drivers
- Trying a different keyboard
- Dell Diagnostics scans
- Turned off "Turn on Toggle Keys by holding down the NUM LOCK key for 5 seconds" in `Control Panel >> All Control Panel Items >> Ease of Access Center >> Make the keyboard easier to use`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out this bizarre NumLock issue is the result of a Microsoft Access bug in a piece of custom software.