Windows 11 PC Numeric Button
How can I permanently activate my numeric button on my PC? I want to make the light button not go off when accidentally pressed?

This post is about disabling the keys, but it's possible the technique can be used to enable. (Assuming it still works, as it's a fairly old question) https://superuser.com/q/688889/105287

To make Windows start with your preferred state, use regedit to find HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Keyboard then set InitialKeyboardIndicators to either 2 (NumLock on)  or 0 (off)
Then physically remove the NumLock keycap to reduce accidental use. Maybe hot glue something like a bottlecap there
